# How can I enqueue an element to a queue of iterables, e.g. Queue[List[Node]]?

Tags: scala, type-inference

The `enqueue` function of `scala.collection.immutable.Queue` is overloaded.

```
def enqueue[B >: A](elem: B]): Queue[B]
def enqueue[B >: A](iter: Iterable[B]): Queue[B]
```

The first signature allows you to add a single item to the queue, and the latter allows you to add multiple items.

I am working on a graph search algorithm and using a queue to keep track of the path (`List[Node]`) I've traversed so far. But when I try to enqueue the path, the compiler assumes I want to use the function with the iterable signature and throws an error.

```
val path = List(Node(0), Node(1), Node(4))
val q: Queue[List[Node]] = Queue[List[Node]]().enqueue(path)
// Expression of type Queue[Product with Serializable] does not conform to expected type Queue[List[Node]]
```

I can get around this by wrapping the path in another list, but this is forced and less clear.

```
val q: Queue[List[Node]] = Queue[List[Node]]().enqueue(List(path))
// compiles
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**
I also noticed the `:+` operator is used only to enqueue single elements, and I like that even better.

```
val q: Queue[List[Node]] = Queue[List[Node]]() :+ path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more explicit about the type parameter of `enqueue`:

```
 q.enqueue[List[Node]](path)
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `enqueue` method. You are using operator [`++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Queue@++[B](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):scala.collection.mutable.Queue[B]), which accepts a list of `B` ([`GenTraversableOnce[B]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce), to be more precisely). You may want to use [`:+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Queue@:+(elem:A):scala.collection.mutable.Queue[A]) operator instead.

Comment: Thanks, @soon. I noticed that before I saw your comment and edited my question. The question is still relevant for the enqueue method.